# Create projection with Empty ICollection in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I have several joins that I want to execute with EF or no depending on certain conditions. I know that I can handle this with anonymous types in my projections but since I want to add additonal data and also include all data from the previous queries and have assignments within if-clauses, it would mean I have to declare variables of IQueryable(of anon-types) which seems to be a big pain (if it is possible at all). So a class type is preferred. The problem I have within my classtype is that it contains one ICollection  (and potentially two more in the future) it's the last one (CarEquipment):

```
Public Class CarFlatRecord
    Public Property Car As Car
    Public Property Make As Make
    Public Property CarEquipment As ICollection(Of CarEquipment) = New List(Of CarEquipment)
End Class
```

EF requires all projections to be equal in order and number of parameters so I have to assign something to CarEquipment, even if I want it to be empty. So far i tried Nothing, / New List() but kept getting EF's various error messages (shown below). Is there any way to assign some empty value in a statement like the following one?

```
dim x= currentContext.Car.
        Join(
            currentContext.Make,
            Function(f) f.MakeId,
            Function(m) m.MakeId,
            Function(left, right) New CarFlatRecord With {.car = f, .make = m, CarEquipment = Nothing}
        )
```

Error messages I get are if I want to assign `CarEquipment=Nothing`:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Model.CarEquipment, Model,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only entity
>   types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this
>   context.

if i completely omit CarEquipment in the first assignment I get

> The type 'BusinessLogic.Data.Lookups.CarFlatRecord' appears in two
>   structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to
>   Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same
>   query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and
>   those properties are set in the same order.

if I try to assign `new List(of CarEquipment)` I get:

> A type that implements IEnumerable
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Model.CarEquipment, Model,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' cannot be
>   initialized in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: Can you provide these "various error messages"?

Comment: This is VB.Net, not C#...

Comment: David; sorry for cross Posting,  c# solutions are just as welcome

Comment: No, you need to pick a language and stick with it, we don't do random tags here.

Comment: @DavidG: ok will behave next time. sorry!

Comment: @AFriend: I updated the question with the erorr messages